# Android gradle build: Adding artifacts to Maven local repository from output folders

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-maven-plugin

I'm using Android-Studio to build a project that have a sub module (AAR).

In my build I'm creating both DEBUG and RELEASE flavors of my APK / AAR.

I used the [android-maven-plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-plugin) to install my APK and AAR to my local repository.

After simple integration I found that my .m2 contains both APK and AAR (including POM.xml files) but also found that this are not the same APK / AAR files as in the build/output folders in the project (which contains the "DEBUG" and "RELEASE" versions).

How can I get the plugin to put the files in the output in my local repository?

While looking for a solution I found that the maven task is depended on ARCHIVES_CONFIGURATION configuration. Should I expect Gradle assembleDebug / assembleRlease to add the artifacts to this configuration?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

I got the [solution](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-plugin/issues/11) from the project forum.

It seems I was missing the `publishNonDefault true` attribute.